# Azure File Storage include file metadata in list request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Is there a way to get Azure to include IListFileItem metadata when calling ListFilesAndDirectories (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectories?view=azure-dotnet)?

I'm making a simple backup script that leverages file metadata and want the script to be as fast and use as few requests as possible. Therefore I do not want to issue a subsequent request for each file to fetch metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today it is not possible. You will need to make a separate call for each file and directory returned in the listing result to fetch the metadata.

[`Cloud​File​Directory.​List​Files​And​Directories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectories?view=azure-dotnet) is essentially a wrapper over [`List Directories and Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files) REST API call and this particular operation does not take a request parameter where you can tell the storage service to return file/directory metadata (you could do such thing when listing blobs in a blob container though).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the ListFilesAndDirectories method will call the [List Directories and Files rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files). It will send the request to list the file and directory. But the result won't contain the file and directory metadata.

The response is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/” ShareName="myshare" DirectoryPath="directory-path">  
  <Marker>string-value</Marker>  
  <MaxResults>int-value</MaxResults>
  <Prefix>prefix-value</Prefix>  
  <Entries>  
    <File>  
      <Name>file-name</Name>  
      <Properties>  
        <Content-Length>size-in-bytes</Content-Length>  
      </Properties>  
    </File>  
    <Directory>  
      <Name>directory-name</Name>  
    </Directory>  
  </Entries>  
  <NextMarker />  
</EnumerationResults>
```

So if you want to get the matedata of the file and directory, the only way is sending another request(call [FetchAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.fetchattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_File_CloudFile_FetchAttributes_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_File_FileRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) method) for each files to get the files or directories' matadata.

Code like this:

```
        foreach (IListFileItem item in result)
        {
            if (item is CloudFile)
            {
                var cloudFile = (CloudFile)item;
                cloudFile.FetchAttributes();
                // You can now access metadata and properties
                var rest = cloudFile.Metadata;
                //cloudFile.Properties
            }
            else if (item is CloudFileDirectory)
            {
                var cloudFileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)item;
                // You can now access metadata and properties
                cloudFileDirectory.FetchAttributes();
               var rest = cloudFileDirectory.Metadata;
                //cloudFileDirectory.Metadata
                //cloudFileDirectory.Properties
            }
        }
```